# When ORDER BY is performed on values aggregated by COUNT, it takes time to issue the query

Tags: sql, postgresql

It tries to retrieve videos in order of the number of tags that are the same as the specific video.

The following query takes about 800ms, but the index appears to be used.
If you remove COUNT, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY from the SQL query, it runs super fast.(1-5ms)

In such a case, improving the SQL query alone will not speed up the process and
Do I need to use MATERIALIZED VIEW?

```sql
SELECT "videos_video"."id",
       "videos_video"."title",
       "videos_video"."thumbnail_url",
       "videos_video"."preview_url",
       "videos_video"."embed_url",
       "videos_video"."duration",
       "videos_video"."views",
       "videos_video"."is_public",
       "videos_video"."published_at",
       "videos_video"."created_at",
       "videos_video"."updated_at",
       COUNT("videos_video"."id") AS "n"
FROM "videos_video"
INNER JOIN "videos_video_tags" ON ("videos_video"."id" = "videos_video_tags"."video_id")
WHERE ("videos_video_tags"."tag_id" IN
       (SELECT U0."id"
        FROM "videos_tag" U0
        INNER JOIN "videos_video_tags" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."tag_id")
        WHERE U1."video_id" = '748b1814-f311-48da-a1f5-6bf8fe229c7f'))
GROUP BY "videos_video"."id"
ORDER BY "n" DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

```
                                                                                                      QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1040.69..1040.74 rows=20 width=24) (actual time=738.648..738.654 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1040.69..1044.29 rows=1441 width=24) (actual time=738.646..738.650 rows=20 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (count(videos_video.id)) DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=987.93..1002.34 rows=1441 width=24) (actual time=671.006..714.322 rows=188818 loops=1)
               Group Key: videos_video.id
               Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 28689kB
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=35.20..980.73 rows=1441 width=16) (actual time=0.341..559.034 rows=240293 loops=1)
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=34.78..340.88 rows=1441 width=16) (actual time=0.278..92.806 rows=240293 loops=1)
                           ->  HashAggregate  (cost=34.35..34.41 rows=6 width=32) (actual time=0.188..0.200 rows=4 loops=1)
                                 Group Key: u0.id
                                 Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB
                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..34.33 rows=6 width=32) (actual time=0.161..0.185 rows=4 loops=1)
                                       ->  Index Only Scan using videos_video_tags_video_id_tag_id_f8d6ba70_uniq on videos_video_tags u1  (cost=0.43..4.53 rows=6 width=16) (actual time=0.039..0.040 rows=4 loops=1)
                                             Index Cond: (video_id = '748b1814-f311-48da-a1f5-6bf8fe229c7f'::uuid)
                                             Heap Fetches: 0
                                       ->  Index Only Scan using videos_tag_pkey on videos_tag u0  (cost=0.28..4.97 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=1 loops=4)
                                             Index Cond: (id = u1.tag_id)
                                             Heap Fetches: 0
                           ->  Index Scan using videos_video_tags_tag_id_2673cfc8 on videos_video_tags  (cost=0.43..35.90 rows=1518 width=32) (actual time=0.029..16.728 rows=60073 loops=4)
                                 Index Cond: (tag_id = u0.id)
                     ->  Index Only Scan using videos_video_pkey on videos_video  (cost=0.42..0.44 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=240293)
                           Index Cond: (id = videos_video_tags.video_id)
                           Heap Fetches: 46
 Planning Time: 1.980 ms
 Execution Time: 739.446 ms
(26 rows)

Time: 742.145 ms
```

---------- Results of the execution plan for the query as answered by Edouard. ----------

```
                                                                                                QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=30043.90..30212.53 rows=20 width=746) (actual time=239.142..239.219 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Limit  (cost=30043.48..30043.53 rows=20 width=24) (actual time=239.089..239.093 rows=20 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=30043.48..30607.15 rows=225467 width=24) (actual time=239.087..239.090 rows=20 loops=1)
               Sort Key: (count(*)) DESC
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=21789.21..24043.88 rows=225467 width=24) (actual time=185.710..219.211 rows=188818 loops=1)
                     Group Key: vt.video_id
                     Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 22545kB
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=20.62..20187.24 rows=320395 width=16) (actual time=4.975..106.839 rows=240293 loops=1)
                           ->  Index Only Scan using videos_video_tags_video_id_tag_id_f8d6ba70_uniq on videos_video_tags vvt  (cost=0.43..4.53 rows=6 width=16) (actual time=0.033..0.043 rows=4 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (video_id = '748b1814-f311-48da-a1f5-6bf8fe229c7f'::uuid)
                                 Heap Fetches: 0
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on videos_video_tags vt  (cost=20.19..3348.60 rows=1518 width=32) (actual time=4.311..20.663 rows=60073 loops=4)
                                 Recheck Cond: (tag_id = vvt.tag_id)
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=34757
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on videos_video_tags_tag_id_2673cfc8  (cost=0.00..19.81 rows=1518 width=0) (actual time=3.017..3.017 rows=60073 loops=4)
                                       Index Cond: (tag_id = vvt.tag_id)
   ->  Index Scan using videos_video_pkey on videos_video v  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=738) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=20)
         Index Cond: (id = vt.video_id)
 Planning Time: 0.854 ms
 Execution Time: 241.392 ms
(21 rows)

Time: 242.909 ms
```

Comment: 1) It seems that you can remove `videos_video` and `videos_tag` because all you need is primary key; 2) after that, you might try inner joining two `videos_video_tags` .

Comment: I'm sorry, but it really is a SELECT like this. How do you deal with this case? Edited question.

Comment: (a) Can you execute your query with no error ? Because you select many columns of the table "videos_video" whereas you only group the rows on "id", and this should lead to an error (b) I do think you can drastically simplify your query with a potential significant impact on the performance (c) I'm not sure a materialized view is relevant in your case, mainly because of the update issue.

Comment: @Edouard grouping by id is sufficient if it is the primary key.

Comment: No particular error occurs. What would be the query to simplify?

Answer (score 1):

Here below are some ideas to simplify the query. Then an `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` will confirm the potential impacts on the query performance.

Starting from the subquery :

```
SELECT U0."id"
  FROM "videos_tag" U0
 INNER JOIN "videos_video_tags" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."tag_id")
 WHERE U1."video_id" = '748b1814-f311-48da-a1f5-6bf8fe229c7f'
```

According to the `JOIN` clause : `U0."id" = U1."tag_id"` so that `SELECT U0."id"` can be replaced by `SELECT U1."tag_id"`.

In this case, the table `"videos_tag" U0` is not used anymore in the subquery which can be simplified as :

```
SELECT U1."tag_id"
  FROM "videos_video_tags" U1
 WHERE U1."video_id" = '748b1814-f311-48da-a1f5-6bf8fe229c7f'
```

And the `WHERE` clause of the main query becomes :

```
WHERE "videos_video_tags"."tag_id" IN
      ( SELECT U1."tag_id"
          FROM "videos_video_tags" U1
         WHERE U1."video_id" = '748b1814-f311-48da-a1f5-6bf8fe229c7f'
      )
```

which can be transformed as a self join on the table `"videos_video_tags"` to be added in the `FROM` clause of the main query :

```
 FROM "videos_video" AS v
INNER JOIN "videos_video_tags" AS vt
   ON v."id" = vt."video_id"
INNER JOIN "videos_video_tags" AS vvt
   ON vvt."tag_id" = vt."tag_id"
WHERE vvt."video_id" = '748b1814-f311-48da-a1f5-6bf8fe229c7f'
```

Finally, the `GROUP BY "videos_video"."id"` clause can be replaced by `GROUP BY "videos_video_tags"."video_id"` according to the `JOIN` clause between both tables, and this new `GROUP BY` clause associated to the `ORDER BY` clause and `LIMIT` clause can apply to a subquery involving the table `"videos_video_tags"` only, and before joining with the table `"videos_video"` :

```
SELECT v."id",
       v."title",
       v."thumbnail_url",
       v."preview_url",
       v."embed_url",
       v."duration",
       v."views",
       v."is_public",
       v."published_at",
       v."created_at",
       v."updated_at",
       w."n"
 FROM "videos_video" AS v
INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT vt."video_id"
           , count(*) AS "n"
        FROM "videos_video_tags" AS vt
       INNER JOIN "videos_video_tags" AS vvt
          ON vvt."tag_id" = vt."tag_id"
       WHERE vvt."video_id" = '748b1814-f311-48da-a1f5-6bf8fe229c7f'
       GROUP BY vt."video_id"
       ORDER BY "n" DESC
       LIMIT 20
    ) AS w
   ON v."id" = w."video_id"
```

Comment: Thank you! Your query execution time has improved a bit! However, I would like to speed it up to around double digits, is it impossible to make it any faster?, I also added the results of the execution plan for this query to the question.

Comment: @Jvn - The execution time has been divided by 3 which is not so bad :-) .The new execution plan is quite interesting but I'm not sure there are so many places for improving the performances - maybe one idea regarding the indexes, and an other one regarding the configuration parameters.  Could you please share the definition of the indexes related to the table "videos_video_tags" ? Thanks.